# Como faço para converter uma data em varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como faço para converter uma data em varchar? Tentei converter para o modo normal, mas não consegui, alguém poderia me ajudar? Desejo que o DT_PAGAMENTO esteja no formato "03/02/2021", em modo dinâmico.

```
SELECT
    NUMERO = CAST(SUBSTRING(BB.IDENT_TITULO, 8, LEN(BB.IDENT_TITULO)) AS BIGINT)
   ,VR_PAGO = CAST(AA.VLOR_PAGO AS FLOAT)/100
   ,DT_PAGAMETO = CONVERT(VARCHAR,AA.DATA_OCORRENCIA,103) <------
   ,DT_VENCIMENTO = BB.DATA_VENC_TITULO
INTO #PAGTO_SENAC
FROM
    #REGISTRO_DETALHE_U AA,
    #REGISTRO_DETALHE_T BB
WHERE
    AA.LOTE = BB.LOTE
    AND AA.ID = BB.ID
```

[data]

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se a tabela temporária criada gerou o tipo DATE para a Data de Pagamento.

Pode ser que o tipo seja diferente de DATE e você esteja tratando com o tipo errado.

Ex:

No código abaixo eu estou tentando converter uma data Varchar em VARCHAR

```
 SELECT DT_PAGAMENTO = convert(varchar, '01022021',103)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, mas eu consegui achar um "atalho" para resolver isso.
Caso alguém mais precise saber como pode funcionar...
`SELECT DT_PAGAMETO = SUBSTRING(AA.DATA_OCORRENCIA, 1,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(AA.DATA_OCORRENCIA,3,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(AA.DATA_OCORRENCIA,5,4)`